# How many objects are created with an Array? [Java]

Tags: java, arrays, oop, object

Hello I would like to know how many objects are created with this array?

```
String arr[] = {"Paul", "Steven", "Jennifer", "Bart"};
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nine objects are created.

Each String is TWO objects. The String reference, and the String's underlying `char[]`. So for 4 strings, that's 8 objects.

Then, there is the `String[]` itself for a total of 9.

This of course assumes the String literal has not been `intern()`ed yet by the JVM. If it has, then it will not create the `String`, but instead pull it from the `intern` pool, which could give you a total of 1, 3, 5, 7, or the original 9 objects created, depending on how many `String`s are `intern`ed.

Comment: Or maybe implementation depended?

Comment: It could be more, although I don't see how it could be less. You will at minimum need the `String[]` reference, a reference for each `String` and one for each `char[]` that backs it. I can't think of what other objects they'd put in there (And checking source has shown there to be none) although it's conceivable they could.

Comment: The strings may have already been created in the JVM, and the array may just borrow the reference directly. So Lenik's right, it's JVM implementation dependent.

Comment: And reference is not an object.

Comment: @RAY That's correct a reference is not an `Object`. But a non-null reference must point to an object. If the Strings have not been interned (as I covered in my edit) then `Object`s will have to be created.

Comment: @glowcoder You've obviously put a lot of thought into this. I look at this question as basically belonging on a naive intro CS test, to see if students will get the "gotcha" that an Array is an Object.

Comment: @glowcoder Think I misread your post. Good catch with the char[] bit.

Comment: @Tim that's what i thought too. Whoever came up with this as a brain teaser deserves some credit, but whoever puts this on an exam should be shot.

Comment: Guys we are talking here about a College class of "Introduction into Java", your explanation is a bit too depth... I would rather guess something between 0-5....

Comment: Okay great thanks a lot, I answered 5 as well, thanks let's see what comes out :P

Comment: @Sebastian, no problem, let us know how we did on your test! lol

Comment: Hahah the test is already written rofl... but I'll let you know next week when I get it back, thx

Comment: @Sebastian One thing to consider is that it may have been written by a TA who has never had a job, and has zero critical thinking skills. He may not realize there's actually 9 `Object`s. That being said, it's sad how *little* critical thinking skills are really taking place. I had to fight with someone about serializing Strings. He said "Two strings of length 16 should take 64 bytes of data." That makes sense, 16*2 bytes per char*2 Strings = 64 bytes. But it turns out it's more like 400+ due to some overhead. Little things *can* matter, but many devs really lack critical thinking skills.

Comment: @glowcoder, I personally would love to learn based with this kind of experienced people, maybe later in an advanced Java class they might consider this, currently they are just going about the basics, which I personally find okay to get the foundation and then later on they can still tell you that it was a lie and actually its 9 objects... But I would love to get to a professor with this extended explanations...

Comment: @Sebastian A true teacher (professor, mentor, friend, anything) will admit when they are factually wrong. Personally, if I had a professor who put 5 down as the answer, and marked me wrong for 9 (given that I explained my answer) I would instantly lose a lot of respect for him.

Comment: @TotalFrickinRockstarFromMars, actually it's only 1, the strings are literals and they are created during the class loading, i.e. Peter's answer is the correct one. (They must be in the pool by java spec. btw). If you do not think of just one, you shall incl. Object[].class, String.class, and char[].class :)

Comment: @bestsss That depends entirely on the semantics of the question and the mood of the professor. If I were grading it, and I saw my answer, I would give it full credit. If I saw Peter's or your comment, I would probably have given bonus credit. That's me personally. In my understanding of the context of the question, it translates more to "How many objects are likely to exist as a direct result of this array?" and not "How many objects exist after calling this statement that didn't exist before?" I believe questions like this are specifically open ended on exams to get people's brains going.

Answer (score 2):

```
String arr[] = {"Paul", "Steven", "Jennifer", "Bart"};
for (Object o : arr) {
   System.out.format("%d\n", o.hashCode());
}
System.out.format("%d\n", arr);
```

You should get 5 distinct hashCode.  A strong suggestion that there now exists 5 objects in your heap.

Comment: Thanks your answer was right from the beginning, others here were just going more into detail, but thanks for the advice with the hashcodes...

Comment: How many objects *exist* after the statement does not -by itself- give information about how many objects were *created by* the statement.

Answer (score 2):

Between 1 and 5 depending on JVM implementation and state. A new String array is apparently created, the Strings - we don't know.

EDIT: As someone pointed out in other answers. 1-9 would be a more precise answer. Since you create a char[] inside a String when it gets constructed.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is none, because `Array` can't create objects, only `new` can. :P

Comment: Opcodes are specified in the JVM spec to work by pushing an appropriately-constructed String object onto the stack. It's implementation dependent, and is possible that if the Strings have been used before that a `String` that's already been `intern()`ed won't have to be created, but we can't rely on that.

Comment: Yes probably but just for primitive data types I think, since String are Objects naturally, you wouldn't need 'new' for creating a new Object.

Comment: For clarity, I was joking, hence the ":P". I will gladly accept down votes as punishment.

Comment: Ohh okay lol I was checking other pages and they were saying 4, which would be impossible, since the array is an object as well, or others also said none, so I was wondering

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you look at it, you could say 9 objects or just one.  If you look at this array in a debugger you will be able to see 9 objects, the array, the String objects and the char[] in those char[].

However the String literals are in a pool and are not created each time (only once) So if you run this line many times you will be only creating the array each time. i.e. only one additional object is created.

Answer (score 0):

HI,

Five objects are created.

If you are using

`int[] i = new int[5];`

then the jvm will create one object on heap.

But if you are providing elements to array for e.g.

```
i[0] = 1;
i[1] = 2;
.
.
i[4] = 5;
```

then the jvm will create six object with five integer and one array object on heap.

Comment: Exactly but you need the 'new' inside of the creation otherwise there would be none, alright thanks guys... Messed up my Java exam :P I really thought 5 but now I remember it has to be with 'new' to actually create the array...

Comment: Ya you can have a look at this link for more help [http://www.coderanch.com/t/418315/java-programmer-SCJP/certification/many-objects-created-array-init]

Comment: No, in this case no objects will be created when you assign values, because `int` is not an object, but a pprimitive type!

Comment: @Sebastian, the code sample you posted includes some syntactic sugar that automatically creates the String Array with size 4, so {"a","b","c","d"} is a String[4].

Comment: @Joachim Sauer :Thanx, you are correct but that was just and example and I also provided a nice link for him to understand it soundly.