# How many objects are in this 2-dimensional array?

Tags: java, arrays

```
int x[][] = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
```

Since arrays are objects and 2-dimensional arrays are arrays of arrays, then how many objects are in this little piece of code?

Comment: How many are they in your opinion and why do you think like that ?

Comment: I want to say either 2 or 3, but I wasn't sure if maybe the whole thing could be considered 1 object.

Comment: Refer here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892905/how-many-objects-are-created-with-an-array-java

Comment: @Joe2013 - This question is substantially different to that one.  This one is about multi-dimensional arrays.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Three.  One for the top level array of `int[]` objects, and two `int[]` objects.

The elements (the integers themselves) are not objects.

---

My criterion for being "an object" is something that has `java.lang.Object` as a direct or indirect supertype.  All array types are implicitly subtypes of `Object`, but `int` is a primitive data type ... and not a subtype of `Object`.

The other thing to note is that `int[][]` means "array of `int[]`" ... in a very literal sense.  The `int[]` objects that you find in an `int[][]` are real, first-class objects.  Your declaration

```
    int[][] x = {{1,2}, {3,4}};
```

is a short-hand for this:

```
    int[][] x = new int[2][]();
    x[0] = new int[]{1, 2};
    x[1] = new int[]{3, 4};
```

Comment: Thank you.
I was leaning towards 3, but I wanted to be sure.
And thanks for not being condescending or giving my question a negative vote.  
I read an entire chapter on arrays and googled for an answer to this question and since it was not explicitly stated anywhere I resorted to stackoverflow. I didn't think it was a dumb question, but some people gave it negative votes.

Comment: And of course `x[0] = new int[]{1, 2};` (which you seem to have typoed as `)`) is itself shorthand.

Comment: @Neil - Thanks.  Right on both counts.  However, I don't need to drill down through the 2nd level of short-hand to make the point I am trying to make.

Comment: Indeed, you only needed to show all of the objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can adopt three point of views:

- There are four `int` values in your 2-dimentional array.
- You can also see a single 1-dimentional array containing two
  1-dimentional arrays, each containing two values.
- A third point of view, centered on `int` vs `arrays` is exposed by
  Stephen C in his answer, which makes three arrays and four `int` values and is actually the second-one rephrased differently (so 3 POVs)